# Redirecting my page to a page URL stored as a session variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following on a page:

```
@{ Session["CurrentUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString(); }
```

I then call another page and in the action method of that page I try to return to the original page using the following

```
return Session["CurrentUrl"] == null ?
    Index() :
    Redirect(Session["CurrentUrl"]);
```

The method seemed good but when I tried to implement this I received errors saying:

```
Error   51  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Redirect(string)' has some invalid arguments    
"Error  52  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string')
```

Can anyone help by telling me what's wrong here. I am not sure how I can fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `Session["CurrentUrl"]` to `string` because the method expects a string

```
return Session["CurrentUrl"] == null ?
    Index() :
    Redirect((string)Session["CurrentUrl"]);
```